# missing value in multirow envoirnment of a table in beamer slide

Tags: tables

i want to add this table in beamer, but when i use multirow envoirnment , values aginst multirows is not showing in the table.

my MWE is as

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}

\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{multirow}


\begin{document}


\begin{frame}{Financial Ind}


\centering

\adjustbox{max height=\dimexpr\textheight-5.5cm\relax,
           max width=\textwidth}{

\rowcolors{1}{tableShade}{white}

\rowcolors[]{2}{blue!20}{pink!30}

\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}

\hline 

\textbf{Institutions (As on March 31, 2013) } & \textbf{Numbers } & \textbf{Balance Sheet Size }\tabularnewline

\hline 

Banks & 38 & 10.14 (Billion US\$)\tabularnewline

\hline 

Development Finance Institutions (DFIs) & 8 & 0.57 (Billion US\$)\tabularnewline

\hline 

Microfinance Institutions (MFIs) & 10 & 0.09 (Billion US\$)\tabularnewline

\hline 

Mutual Funds & 144 & .01 (Billion US\$)\tabularnewline

\hline 

Modaraba Companies & 21 & \multirow{8}{*}{0.09 (Billion US\$)}\tabularnewline

\cline{1-2} 

Asset Management Companies & 18 & \tabularnewline

\cline{1-2} 

Leasing Companies & 10 & \tabularnewline

\cline{1-2} 

Pension Funds & 23 & \tabularnewline

\cline{1-2} 

Investment Banks & 8 & \tabularnewline

\cline{1-2} 

Cooperative Banks + Venture Capital & 2 + 1 & \tabularnewline

\cline{1-2} 

Insurance Companies & 51 & \tabularnewline

\cline{1-2} 

Exchange Companies & 56 & \tabularnewline

\hline 

\end{tabular}

}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\multirow` value gets overprinted by the row background color. Therefore `\multirow` should go in the last line and puts the text above (negative row number in the argument of `\multirow`):

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}{Financial Ind}
\centering

\adjustbox{max height=\dimexpr\textheight-5.5cm\relax,
           max width=\textwidth}{%
\rowcolors{1}{tableShade}{white}%
\rowcolors[]{2}{blue!20}{pink!30}%
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}
\hline 
\textbf{Institutions (As on March 31, 2013) } & \textbf{Numbers } & \textbf{Balance Sheet Size }\tabularnewline
\hline 
Banks & 38 & 10.14 (Billion US\$)\tabularnewline
\hline 
Development Finance Institutions (DFIs) & 8 & 0.57 (Billion US\$)\tabularnewline
\hline 
Microfinance Institutions (MFIs) & 10 & 0.09 (Billion US\$)\tabularnewline
\hline 
Mutual Funds & 144 & .01 (Billion US\$)\tabularnewline
\hline 
Modaraba Companies & 21 & \tabularnewline
\cline{1-2} 
Asset Management Companies & 18 & \tabularnewline
\cline{1-2} 
Leasing Companies & 10 & \tabularnewline
\cline{1-2} 
Pension Funds & 23 & \tabularnewline
\cline{1-2} 
Investment Banks & 8 & \tabularnewline
\cline{1-2} 
Cooperative Banks + Venture Capital & 2 + 1 & \tabularnewline
\cline{1-2} 
Insurance Companies & 51 & \tabularnewline
\cline{1-2} 
Exchange Companies & 56 & \multirow{-8}{*}{0.09 (Billion US\$)}\tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remark:**

- The argument of `\adjustbox` is put in horizontal mode, therefore the line ends matter and adds spaces to the left and right. The example removes them by commenting them (putting `%` at the end of line).